# What is an example of a continuous function where the derivative at $x=0$ does not exist?

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

> What is an example of a continuous function where the derivative at $x=0$ does not exist?

This is a word problem, and I don't know how to approach this because it is an unusual question. Any Hints?

Comment: One easy way to find a function with a non-existent derivative at a point is to find a function with a sharp corner. What function do you know that have a corner?

Comment: This should've been an answer @Alex S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest example is the absolute value function.

Comment: What are some other functions without modulus? :)

Comment: $f(x) = x^{1/3}$

Comment: Wow :O How did you know that?

Comment: Is there a specific method to these?

Comment: Think how the plots of these functions look.